# Munin-node won't start Cent OS 5.7

Tags: centos, munin

i just installed munin-node on my new cent os 5.7 64bit machine via yum.

Installation went fine, i've setup munin and munin-nodes on many machines in the past, but this time i cannot get it to start.

When I try to restart it with the following command this happens:

```
[root@Server2 munin]# service munin-node restart
Stopping Munin Node agents: kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
                                                           [FAILED]
Starting Munin Node: Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/Net/Server/Daemonize.pm line 61.
Couldn't find pid in existing pid_file at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/Net/Server/Daemonize.pm line 61.
                                                           [  OK  ]
```

It says [OK] in the end in green, but I don't see it running anywhere.

Also this is the output of munin-node.log

```
[root@Server2 munin]# tail -n 100 munin-node.log
2011/12/04-03:10:44 Couldn't find pid in existing pid_file at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/Net/Server/Daemonize.pm line 61.

  at line 276 in file /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/Net/Server.pm
2011/12/04-03:10:44 Server closing!
2011/12/04-03:10:54 Couldn't find pid in existing pid_file at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/Net/Server/Daemonize.pm line 61.

  at line 276 in file /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/Net/Server.pm
2011/12/04-03:10:54 Server closing!
```

Ive looked up line 61 in Daemonize.pm and it is:

```
  my $current_pid = $_current_pid =~ /^(\d{1,10})/ ? $1 : die "Couldn't find pid in existing pid_file";
```

I've tried to rename the pid file in /etc/munin/munin-node.conf  but that also didnt change anything.

Output of:

> [root@Server2 plugins]# sudo /usr/sbin/munin-node-configure --suggest

http://pastebin.com/Yd6eX5Ss which seems all perfect to me.

Any idea what I can try?

Comment: Might try this Q on http://serverfault.com/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the original PID file fixed the problem.